# Using a Promise to check if a new random number has been generated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, smartcontracts, chainlink

I'm using Chainlink Oracles to get random numbers. This process of getting a random number takes a while. In order to do that, I have to execute this line (asynchronous call), which calls a function of my smart contract an stores the new random number:

```
const newRandomNumber = await contract.connect(signer).randomResult();
```

What I want is to automate this process: when a new number is generated (and it is available for use), I would like to display a message to the user (in my fronted).

> Hey, a new number has been generated.

How could I periodically check if the result stored in `newRandomNumber` has changed? And how could I display a message when that has happened?

Comment: Could you provide the link of the documentation on how a random number is provided or show an example code that specifically gets a random number?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking; are you wondering how promises work? How to call a function repeatedly? Please clarify a bit so people can give you a more specific answer :)

Comment: @MarcRo thanks for help. I have simplified the question.

Comment: @code I'm not sure if that's important. I mean, I'm only concerning about frontend part. That line gets a random number, but it takes about 2 minutes, so I don't know the exact time the number is generated. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Joncarre, thanks this makes it a bit clearer. I am not familiar with the capabilities of your smart contract. Will it generate a new random number on each call? Or will it periodically generate a number that is stored on chain and your `randomResult()` call merely retrieves the currently stored number?

Comment: @MarcRo It is a two-stage process. The first phase generates the number (using another function), and the second phase captures (this one) the number. That call is a `get` function to catch the number (which has already been previously generated). So, somehow I want to automatically check if the new number is available. And, when it is, display a message. That is, I don't want to press a button periodically to check if the number has changed.

Comment: @Joncarre I see! So some other logic/app triggers the generation and your question is only concerned with checking whether it updated. Are you aware whether your smart contract has the ability to notify apps about this change? E.g. by calling a webhook when this chamge occurs? Otherwise you would have to periodically call the getter... Thats not complicated but potentially fires many unnecessary requests.

Comment: @MarcRo ty for answer. Hummm I´ll try to find if I can do something in my back, but usually it´s more expensive. Meanwhile I rather do it on my frontend. How could I do it? Call it periodically and show a message, I mean.

Comment: I see, okay. I will write an answer with an example later when I'm home!

Comment: @MarcRo Thanks! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

Create an **[Observable](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable)** to periodically call an API-endpoint:

```js
import { distinctUntilChanged, switchMap, timer } form 'rxjs'; /* Use RxJS library for convenience */

const getRandomNumber = contract.connect(signer).randomResult();

const observable = timer(0, 1000) /* Trigger now and each 1000 ms */
    .pipe(
        switchMap(getRandomNumber), /* On each run, get the current number */
        distinctUntilChanged(), /* Only trigger subscribers if new number */
    )

const subscription = observable.subscribe((number) => console.log(number));

/* Don't forget to unsubscribe after, e.g. when the component unmounts */
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

## Long version

The observer pattern allows you to receive notifications (e.i. 'subscribe') to multiple asynchronous events - the same way a javascript `Promise` notifies you after a single asynchronous event finished. (Observers are actually much more flexible than that, this is merely one usecase)

### A naive javascript implementation

Let's see how we could implement your desired behavior in basic javascript

```js
let currentRandomNumber = null;
let isCanceled = false;

async function checkAndUpdateNumber() {
  while (!isCanceled) {
    /* Set your new (or same) number */
    currentRandomNumber = await contract.connect(signer).randomResult();

    /* Wait 1000ms */
    await new Promsie((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
}
checkAndUpdateNumber();

/* If you want to stop the loop */
isCancelled = true;
```

This implementation works but leaves much room for improvement. The code is not reusable in the slightest and is not easily testable.

Observers provide you with a much cleaner interface to handle multiple asynchronous operations. Check out [this](https://netbasal.com/javascript-observables-under-the-hood-2423f760584) article to get an idea of how observers work under the hood.

The go-to javascript library for observables is [RxJS](https://rxjs.dev). It is well tested and provides countless utility methods so I'd highly recommend you to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Because you tagged React on your question, here's a commented example using React state:

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.16.6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

const {useEffect, useState} = React;

// simulate making a network request to get a random number from an API:
// it will return a promise which will (at some point in the future)
// resolve with the random number, or reject with an Error
function mockFetchRandomNumber () {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1; // 1-1000
  const delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1000; // 1-2s
  const chance = 0.2; // percent chance of random network failure
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => {
    if (chance > Math.random()) reject(new Error('Network error'));
    else resolve(randomNumber);
  }, delay));
}

// a custom hook to wrap the logic of fetching the random number
// and maintain the state of the request while doing so
function useRandomNumber () {
  const [data, setData] = useState(); // the potential data
  const [error, setError] = useState(); // a potential error
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false); // whether the request is still pending
  const [reloadBoolean, setReloadBoolean] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      setData(undefined);
      setError(undefined);
      try {
        const randomNumber = await mockFetchRandomNumber();
        setData(randomNumber);
        setError(undefined);
      }
      catch (ex) {
        setError(ex instanceof Error ? ex : new Error(String(ex)));
        setData(undefined);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [reloadBoolean, setData, setError, setIsLoading]);

  return {
    data,
    error,
    isLoading,
    // will toggle the value of `reloadBoolean`, forcing a re-render
    reload: () => setReloadBoolean(b => !b),
  };
}

function Example () {
  const {data, error, isLoading, reload} = useRandomNumber();
  return (
    <div>
      {
        isLoading
          ? (<div>Loading random number...</div>)
          : null
      }
      {
        error
          ? (<div>There was an error loading the data ({error.message})</div>)
          : null
      }
      {
        data
          ? (<div>The random number is: {data}</div>)
          : null
      }
      <button onClick={reload}>Get new number</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```